# What is the difference between the gazebo differential drive plugin and a differential drive controller spawned by controller_spawner?

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the difference between

- a controller specified by 
  in a  tag, in an URDF file, and
- a controller spawned by a controller_manager spawner node of type "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209389/what-is-the-difference-between-the-gazebo-differential-drive-plugin-and-a-differential-drive-controller-spawned-by-controller_spawner?/) by [nodge](https://answers.ros.org/users/21149/nodge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2015-05-17

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- a controller specified by 
  in a  tag, in an URDF file, and

This is a Gazebo plugin, and hence will work only in Gazebo ([doc](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#DifferentialDrive)).

- a controller spawned by a controller_manager spawner node of type "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"

This is a `ros_control` plugin, and will work with any supported robot backend, and includes not only Gazebo, but `ros_control`-enabled hardware, and potentially other simulators as well ([doc](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller)).

Feature-wise they seem roughly similar: take twist commands, publish odometry. I would suggest you to look at the documentation of each alternative and figure out which works best for your setup.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/5055/zheng/) on 2018-07-13**:
It seems that now these two behaves quite differently by default. On my current setup (ros-kinetic-desktop-full with Gazebo7), the gazebo plugin works well with joint defined with EffortJointInterface. But the ros_control plugin seems to be requiring VelocityJointInterface.