# Difference between libgazebo_ros2_control.so and libgazebo_ros_diif_drive.so plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin, plugin, ros2-control, diff-drive-controller

What is difference between libgazebo_ros2_control.so and libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so plugin?

How this two plugins are used to control the robot?

Comment: To clarify, this question is a duplicate of [what's the difference between "diff_drive_controller" and "libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so" ?](https://answers.ros.org/question/331442/whats-the-difference-between-diff_drive_controller-and-libgazebo_ros_diff_driveso/), which in turn was flagged as a duplicate of the *now migrated*, [What is the difference between the gazebo differential drive plugin and a differential drive controller spawned by controller_spawner?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/67631/what-is-the-difference-between-the-gazebo-differential-drive-plugin-and-a-differ)